# Flutter "Entrypoint isn't within the current project." error on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, entry-point

Flutter app runs on VS Code with Start Debugging & Run Without Debugging and also with terminal command "flutter run" .
However it runs on Android Stuido only with terminal command "flutter run".

When I try to run it on Android Studio, with the play button which triggers the build, I get this error :
"Entrypoint isn't within the current project."

Invalidate Caches and Restart, flutter clean, quitting and restarting Android Studio are some options I tired with no success at all.

Have any of you faced the same issue?
What can be the problem? And please the solution...

Thanks in advance,
Oz

Here's the image of Run Config :[image]

Comment: Can also try this which helped me. Delete the .idea folder inside the flutter project and restart the android studio

Comment: Did you set your own custom "Run Configuration" or are you using the default one? If yes, can you share with us the details, or better yet, a screenshot of your "Run Configuration" tool window?

Comment: I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: Then it's one of the obvious - make sure the file is actually at that location and try one without whitespaces or characters that need escaping

Comment: It's exactly there.  When I press "Run" I get another pop up window telling that 

"Change Configuration Settings
 Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?"

What is the problem really ? It works with "flutter run" and on VS code. But not on Android Studio...

Answer (score 3):

Click on File-> Project Structure -> Module then add root folder of your project then it will detect its a flutter app and then build

Comment: Thank you. This is a common answer I've seen on similar questions. But my project does not have File-> Project Structure -> Module . It has Default Project Structure item, which does not lead to Module... 

Invalidate Caches and Restart, flutter clean, quitting and reopening Android Studio are some other stuff I tired with no success at all..

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, hope it will work for everyone.
Goto File -> Project Structure -> Module
Or
in edit configuration, just name it "main" and locate the location of 'main.dart' file in the Dart entrypoint text field.
Please take a look at the below screenshot.

[Run/Debug Configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KolW.png)